# How to create calendar reminders in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I can create calendar events using [add_2_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/add_2_calendar) like this:

```
 final Event newEvent = Event(
      title: "title",
      description: "description",
      location: "address",
      startDate: _fromDate,
      endDate: _toDate.add(
        Duration(minutes: 30),
      ),
    );

    Add2Calendar.addEvent2Cal(newEvent);
```

But what can I use to create calendar reminders? I need to create birthdays notifications:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [device_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/device_calendar). You can create events as well as reminders using it

Comment: that package has no instructions. Could you provide an example?